# Django signals not triggered when a model object is created

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-celery, django-signals

I am using Django signals to trigger a task (sending mass emails to subscribers using django celery package)when an admin post a blogpost is created from Django admin. But the signal is not triggered. I have a print statement inside the signal which is not printing ie the signal is not recived after a new blog is created.

My apps are set like this.

[image]

My blog model:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):

    author = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Admin')    
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    .................../
```

My tasks file

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from travel_crm.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER

    @shared_task
    def send_mails(self,*args, **kwargs):
    
        subscribers = self.kwargs['subscribers']
        blog = self.kwargs['blog']
        for abc in subscribers:
            emailad = abc.email
            send_mail('New Blog Post ', f" Checkout our new blog with title {blog.title} ",
                      EMAIL_HOST_USER, [emailad],
                      fail_silently=False)
```

My signals.py file

```
from .tasks import send_mails
from apps.blogs.models import BlogPost,Subscribers
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


    @receiver(post_save, sender=BlogPost)
    def email_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        print(123456789)
        if created:
            print(123456789)
            subscribers = Subscribers.objects.all()
            blog = BlogPost.objects.latest('date_created')
            print(blog)
            # task = send_mails(subscribers, blog)
            # task.delay()
            send_mails.delay(subscribers,blog)
```

My init file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from apps.blogs.celery_files.celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Comment: Your code examples are non-functional. You're providing methods without classes (`def send_mail`) and snippets from your model that are even missing fields that you are using in other snippets (`date_created`). Are you sure this problem is mail specific - in other words can you confirm that celery works properly in general?

Comment: I have used ..... in Blogpost as there are many fields which I dont need to write here so...

Answer (score 3):

you must import your `signals.py` somewhere for it to be registered, the django documentation suggests to import it in the `ready()` method inside `apps.py` file of the app like so:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class BlogsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blogs'

    def ready(self):
        import blogs.celery_files.signals
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

Comment: I did this, but still I dont get print result of 123456789. what is the issue??

Answer (score 0):

Check your *my tasks file* file. Did you share the entire file?

You wrote:

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail

from travel_crm.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER

    @shared_task
    def send_mails(self,*args, **kwargs):
    
        subscribers = self.kwargs['subscribers']
        blog = self.kwargs['blog']
        for abc in subscribers:
            emailad = abc.email
            send_mail('New Blog Post ', f" Checkout our new blog with title {blog.title} ",
                      EMAIL_HOST_USER, [emailad],
                      fail_silently=False)
```

If this is the entire file, you have multiple issues that need to be fixed:

1. using the `@shared_task` decorator without the corresponding import
   `from celery import shared_task`
2. wrong intendation -
   there is no reason for the function to be intended
3. using the `self` argument outsite a class

You have the same intendation problem within signals.py.

Comment: There is no indentation in every file. I don't know how it shows indentation here. I have imported shared_task(otherwise it doesn't work) there i didn't post here which is my mistake. The main issue is signals code is not running in the first place, as the print is not showing.